# async & await problem in multi threads code

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have this simple situation:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  Task t;
  public Form1() {
     InitializeComponent();
     t = Prepare();
  }

  public Task waitT() {
     return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T works \n");
        }
     });
  }
  public Task waitT2() {
     return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T2 works \n");
        }
     });
  }

  public Task waitT3() {
     return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T3 works \n");
        }
     });
  }

  public async Task Prepare() {
     //await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
        await waitT();
        Console.WriteLine("T DOne.");
        await waitT2();
        Console.WriteLine("T2 DOne.");
        await waitT3();
        Console.WriteLine("T3 DOne.");
    // });
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
     base.OnPaint(e);
     t.Wait();
     Console.WriteLine("Finish");
  }
```

}

In a few words, i want start a task in constructor, and wait some data in Paint events. The problem is that the execution is blocked in wait() method and the code Console.WriteLine("T DOne.") is never  called. I have read that the execution of asynch methods is in a first time synch and i think that the problem is this.
To try to solve the problem i have changed my code of function prepare in this way:

```
 public async Task Prepare() {
     return await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
        await waitT();
        Console.WriteLine("T DOne.");
        await waitT2();
        Console.WriteLine("T2 DOne.");
        await waitT3();
        Console.WriteLine("T3 DOne.");
     });
  }
```

In this way the situation change, and the wait method in paint is not respected, and the execution pass immediately to Console.WriteLine("Finish") and Prepare process is running to completition.

Probably i m committing a concectual error, someone can explain me the correct approach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Besides poorly understanding async/await, this is a terrible idea.. You really don't want to be waiting around in a paint event

Comment: i used paint like an example, but i can use other events.....

Comment: It's advisable to use the `Task.Run()`

Comment: Nothing change...

Comment: The whole conceptual problem lies that you call the `Prepare` in the constructor. The constructor cannot be part of the state-machine.

Comment: sorry, but i cannot understand why call Prepare in constructor is the problem...if i have ref to task why i cannot wait him in some other event?

Comment: You should read this: [Async OOP 2: Constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)

Comment: you can await `Prepare` in any event. You simply need to declare the event `async` then. Your problem is that you cannot do it with the constructor

Comment: I'd say the core problem is *requiring* the task to be complete in the `OnPaint`. There should never be a need for that. If the task isn't complete (i.e., the data isn't available), then paint something *else*, like a loading message. Then, when the task completes (i.e., the data arrives), you can *update* to display that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into a deadlock because you switch from async to sync and the 2 things/processes have different synchronization contextes. 
You cannot make the constructor async but as a workaround you can wrap it into a waiting task:

```
public Form1() {
     InitializeComponent();
     Task.WaitAll(Task.Run( async ()=> await Prepare()));
}
```

You don't really need the `Task t` variable. Since `Prepare` does not yield any return values you can simply await it. I guess you made this example to represent some problem that you have. Normally if you start with `async` and `await` you need to pump it up to the highest level of the GUI. Any break to synchronous processing will cause a deadlock

EDIT:
After your comment:

> i want to create a long running task (Example wrong in constructor), run it, and when i need the result check if the task is finished or not for example in event.

I would suggest to start the task in the constructor:

```
t = Task.Run(async ()=> await Prepare());
```

and await it in the `OnPaint` event which you have to make `async` so it does not block the UI:

```
protected override async void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine($"Finish");
}
```

Comment: Yes i have used simple code, i have more difficult situation in my code... i have used t variable because i need in my code to know the state of my task because in different methods i need his result....

Comment: @TheOverrider do you want to await the `Prepare` method in an event or in a constructor?

Comment: i need to await the finish of prepare NOT in constructor, for example in event.

Comment: @TheOverrider please post an event example, and I will incorporate it into my answer.

Comment: @TheOverrider ahh, do you want to create a task in the constructor first, and then actually execute it in the `OnPaint` event? is that your intention?

Comment: no, i want to create a long running task (Example wrong in constructor), run it, and when i need the result check if the task is finished or not for example in event.

Comment: @TheOverrider I made an edit to my answer after your comment. Have a look. May be this time I understood you better

Comment: Yes @Mong Zhu, i have change my 2 edit in a way similar with yours some seconds before notification. This is my goal situation.Thanks.

Comment: @TheOverrider glad to hear, you still should make the event async and await the task in there. `t.Wait` is synchronous and will block the GUI

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
I have change my code, i have removed the task assignment from constructor and moved it in load event:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {
  Task t;
  public Form1() {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
     base.OnLoad(e);
     t = Prepare();
  }

  public Task waitT() {
     return Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T works \n");
        }
     });
  }
  public Task waitT2() {
     return Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T2 works \n");
        }
     });
  }

  public Task waitT3() {
     return Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T3 works \n");
        }
     });
  }

  public async Task Prepare() {
     await Task.Run(async () => {
        await waitT();
        Console.WriteLine("T DOne.");
        await waitT2();
        Console.WriteLine("T2 DOne.");
        await waitT3();
        Console.WriteLine("T3 DOne.");
     });
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
     base.OnPaint(e);
     t.Wait();
     Console.WriteLine("Finish");
  }
```

}

Now the result is different, i wait correct the end 3 wait methods, but the execution remains blocked in t.wait() despite the end of 3 methods....
Console.WriteLine("Finish"); not called :(

[EDIT 2]
Probably i have solved my problem, and i can use different approach to create a task in constructor, this code works fine ( This is only and example with event):

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {
  Task t;
  public Form1() {
     InitializeComponent();
     t = Prepare();
  }

  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
     base.OnLoad(e);
  }

  public Task waitT() {
     return Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T works \n");
        }
     });
  }
  public Task waitT2() {
     return Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T2 works \n");
        }
     });
  }

  public Task waitT3() {
     return Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           Console.WriteLine("T3 works \n");
        }
     });
  }

  public Task Prepare() {
     return Task.Run(async () => {
        await waitT();
        Console.WriteLine("T DOne.");
        await waitT2();
        Console.WriteLine("T2 DOne.");
        await waitT3();
        Console.WriteLine("T3 DOne.");
     });
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
     base.OnPaint(e);
     t.Wait();
     Console.WriteLine("Finish");
  }
```

}